# Adding GitHub repository with commits from secondary mail

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs, email

I tried to add a GitHub repository to my Careers profile, in which I only made commits with an old email which I don't have access anymore to. It doesn't show on my Careers profile, because it says that I haven't contributed to the project, though the commits are associated to my profile. There is no way I could rewrite the old commits, because they were already merged in the original repo.

Should I make a bogus commit in my own fork with my primary mail address?

Comment: Actually the repos were correctly added